# Having difficulty installing R package in specific directory

Tags: r, package, rcurl

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  This seems very strange to me.  I am trying to install packages on an AWS server running Concerto with the following command.  concerto$mediaPath is a list item that targets a writable directory.

```
lib=paste0(concerto$mediaPath,"/lib")
dir.create(lib)
install.packages("RCurl", lib=lib, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
library("RCurl", lib=lib)
```

After running the command it seems to install RCurl without error but the library command produces an error that says "RCurl" cannot be found.  If I do:

```
dir(lib)
```

It says that "bitops" is in the created folder but not "RCurl".  I believe RCurl has a dependency on bitops which explains why it was installed but not why RCurl did not install.

Any ideas would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you can create that directory AND that you can see it on `.libPaths()` ...  Then you also need to make sure that your system is configured to meet this requirement in the DESCRIPTION file:

```
SystemRequirements: libcurl (version 7.14.0 or higher)
    http://curl.haxx.se. On Linux systems, you will often have to
    explicitly install libcurl-devel to have the header files and
    the libcurl library.
```

First version erroneously left off the "." from `.libPaths()`

Comment: probably this is the cause for the issue.. just tried on my mac. seems to work fine.